# Fgets cutting off for some stdin

Tags: c, string, buffer, stdin, fgets

I'm having a weird problem with fgets.

If the command is such as this: $test.txt, fgets recieves it completely with no problem.
If the command is such as this: $ls -l > test.txt, the result is this:

```
Buffer: ls -l > test.t
```

Cuts off the xt and I get a segmentation fault.

This is my code:

```
void ReadCommand(char *buffer, size_t len)
{
    if(fgets(buffer, len, stdin) != NULL)
        buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Code that calls this method:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        ...
    char cmd_line[MAX_ARG_LEN]; //MAX_ARG_LEN = 16
    size_t len = sizeof(cmd_line);

    /* Read Command Line */
    ReadCommand(cmd_line, len);
        ...

}
```

The periods signify there's stuff before and after. But they are irrelevant to anything to do with the buffer or the function.

I don't know why that happens. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';` replaces the last character in `buffer`.  You haven't provided enough detail for us to answer the rest of the question.  Can you show a full example program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you show; the problem is in the code you don't show — the code which calls this.  The only issue here is the almost hypothetical problem of 'what happens if `len < 2`?', or if the buffer is a null pointer.

Comment: I've updated it! Please take a look.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the calling code shown. Time to go for an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)), eliminating code and demonstrating that the problem still occurs each time you remove code.  I suspect that something somewhere else is trampling on memory, but have no proof of that.  Have you tried running under `valgrind`?  It might help; it might not (especially, it probably won't help much if you do no dynamic memory allocation yourself).

Comment: I figured the problem out. The size of the cmd_line array was apparently too small. Had to be bigger.